# Какая разница между сервлетом и веб сервисом?

Tags: java, servlet, веб-служба, jax-rs, jax-ws

Начинаю знакомиться с веб. Рассматриваю примеры HelloWorld'ов, где в некоторых приводится реализация с использованием сервлетов, и при открытии соответствющей страницы с определенным URL адресом выводится текст. В другом примере делают то же самое, только с использованием веб сервиса (JAX WS), но чуть сложнее, создается сам сервис, потом по сгенерированному WSDL файлу клиент, и уже посредством запуска клиента в браузер выводится легендарный HelloWorld. 
Вот не понимаю какая между ними разница, если и там и там может быть реализована какая либо логика с обращением к БД и т.д. 
Если я захожу на какую нибудь страницу с картинкой, мне ее отправляет сервлет или сервис?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930795/difference-between-servlet-and-web-service